# Почему сокращённые названия субъектов РФ "Мособласть", "Ленобласть" очень широко распространены, а вот сокращённые названия других субъектов нет?

Tags: топонимика

**Мособласть** — сокращение от Московская область, **Ленобласть** — сокращение от Ленинградская область. Такие сокращённые названия этих субъектов РФ очень широко распространены в русском языке, особенно в СМИ. Так почему сокращённые названия других субъектов РФ, помимо Московской и Ленинградской областей, не так широко распространены, как **Мособласть** и **Ленобласть**?